# nodejs is there a better option to put every variable on ram?

Tags: node.js, express

I develop a multi tenant application and saw this tutorial to handle the tenant database connections:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {   //initiate middleware
 
query = "SELECT tenant_db FROM tenants WHERE tenant_id = 
         (SELECT tenant_id 
         FROM tenant_user WHERE user_id = ?)"
  connectors['common_db'].query(query, [req.session.user_id], 
    
    function(err, result) {
      if(!err) {
         tenant_db = null;
         if(result.length > 0) {
            tenant_db = result[0].tenant_db
         }

         req.app.db_conn = connectors[tenant_db]
      }  
      else{
         console.log(err)
      }
      next()    
  })
```

You see req.app.db_conn = connectors[tenant_db] is stored in a variable

Is there a better way to store it ?

Should I use redis for the storage or is that overkill ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to store her? cause db connections are not simply values, when create db connection in nodejs, actual tcp connection is made by os over tcp and then return the mapped socket info, if the nodejs server gets restarted these connections are terminated so no use of keeping these data externally.

Comment: @v1shva I saw this article https://medium.com/@lukas.noebauer/a-simplistic-approach-to-implement-multi-tenancy-in-node-js-a5eee59500e6 and when you have a lot of server variable you can get out of ram so what would be a better way to store this connection variable for each tenant ?